# "Avoided poor Internet connection" on LG G2

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, lg-g2

I'm trying to connect to my home's wireless router with my new **LG G2 (running version 4.2.2)** and it keeps saying "Obtaining IP address..." for three minutes, then momentarily saying "Saved, secured", before cycling through all over again. It does this about 5 times and then eventually stops trying and says "Avoided poor Internet connection".

It seems that the problem is only affecting my Android device. My laptop can connect; my mother's and girlfriend's iPhones can both connect; and this is the second Android device I've had with this connection issue (my old Droid 4 had it too).

I can't figure out what the problem could be. I've tried changing the broadcast channels on the router with no luck, and I'm too worried to mess around with the network settings much more, for fear of messing up the network for more devices.

On top of this, with the recent phone upgrade and data transfer, I'm at 90% of my monthly data usage, with half a month yet to go. :[

What can I do to connect to the wireless, short of getting a new phone or new router?

***[EDIT 1]*** OK. So now I've tried using my desktop as a mobile hotspot, and this is still not working. Perhaps the most troubling part is that it isn't working even when I bypass the router altogether, and plug the computer directly into the modem. It even failed both with and without encryption.

***[EDIT 2]*** Here is a screenshot of the Advanced Wi-Fi settings, as requested.

[image: advanced wi-fi]
<sup>Click image for larger variant</sup>

Comment: I have tried this and just about everything but my WiFi still is not connecting, it says saved and secured and when I press connect it connects for about 2 seconds, yes, I have tried 're entering my WiFi password but even that won't wont

Comment: If your device rooted? + Try this... disable WiFi connection, put your phone in "Airplane mode" and then turn on WiFi again, and check if it results the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `Settings` --> `Wifi`-->(press menu) `Advanced`--> uncheck "`Avoid Poor Connections`" checkbox.
Then Click on network Available. Now it will connect(or else click `forget` and re-enter your password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this option isn't listed anywhere in the menu. The only "advanced" options are (1) Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep [always] (2) Wi-Fi signal weak [unchecked] (3) Internet unavailable [unchecked] (4) Wi-Fi (battery) optimization [checked] (5) Manage networks

Comment: I was on the Advanced menu.

Comment: Pls mention device and OS version.

Comment: I thought LG G2 with Android 4.2.2 was enough. The software version is VS98012B, if that helps.

Comment: Could you please post a screen shot of Advanced Settings menu

Comment: Added one to the initial post.